# Insert data from one table to another table

Tags: sql, join

I want to insert data from one table to another but
my issue is if I run SP second time it should not insert which data is already present
KEY is Productcode

i should use joins(no syubquery)

```
INSERT INTO ProductCategoryMapping2
                    ( [ProductCode]
                    , [ProductName]
                    , [Category]
                    , [IsActive]
                    , [Division]
                    , [SubCategory])
        SELECT  TRIM(STR(MATCODE, 25, 0)) AS MATCODE
                    , MATNAME
                    , [OPERATIONS_PROD_CATEGORY_NAME]
                    ,IIF([MAT_BRAND_STATUS_NAME] = 'Active',1,0) as [IsActive]
                    ,[OPERATIONS_PROD_DIVISION_NAME]
                    , [OPERATIONS_PROD_SUBCATEGORY_NAME]
                    FROM [dbo].[Sheet1$] s
```

this code insert all data to destination table each and every time

Comment: Why don't you check on productcode? Insert only if it doesn't exist

Comment: using subquery i did it, but using joins i need to do......................... this is my sub query
SELECT  * FROM [dbo].[Sheet1$] s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT *  from ProductCategoryMapping2 where [ProductCode] = TRIM(STR(s.MATCODE, 25, 0)) )

Comment: Please include all information in your question

Comment: ok. simple i need query that fetch data from source table to destination table, if the row data already in destination table that data should not be inserted (in other word no duplicate should not be there in destination table ) .. query should do using joins...


please share sample query . in my case ProductCode is PKid  for both table

Comment: And what is wrong with using `not exists`? Why do you need joins?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to find new data, not present in the destination table, you have to add a left join with the destination table and filter by key=NULL

This is not a working example but can guide you to write the actual query:

```
LEFT JOIN ProductCategoryMapping2 destination ON s.key = destination.key
WHERE destination.key IS NULL
```

We are aiming for the second left join in this picture.

[image]